# When to perform my unit test and why use Moq

Tags: unit-testing, testing, moq, repository-pattern

**Q1:** When is it ideal to run unit test? Should it be ran before each time I go to debug the app? Should they be ran before I commit changes to svn? I think if an app only has a couple of unit test it should be ran each time the app is about to debug. But lets say we hundreds of unit test that can take a bit of time to complete, not sure if this is ideal or not. I think then it would be better to just run them before committing or deploying.

**Q2:** In my app Im using a repository pattern with a service layer. I've done some research on how to test a service when the service is calling a repository and the repository is querying db. So in order for it to be a true unit test and not an integration test, I have to find a way to test without touching the database. I found people are using Moq to mock their repository. Here's where I have a problem, to me it seems if I mock a repository then I'm changing the behavior of how the method is suppose to work and to me seems like a pointless unit test. It doesn't seem you are actually testing **your** code. Am I completley wrong about this? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take a shot.

A1: When you refactor existing code, you should execute the corresponding unit tests (not all) and see if anything is broken by your changes. For new functionality you should implement new unit tests in parallel using TDD. You should never execute all the unit tests by your own but should use or rely on continuous integration.

A2: I had a same opinion like you. But now, I am convinced that unit testing for service layer is required. Whatever that can be covered using unit testing should be covered. At this point, the core of your services might just be a delegation to repositories but services evolves. The services takes up the responsibility of parameter validation, authorization, logging, transactions, batch-support API etc. Then, it is not only data-access but many more things. If I were in your place, I would go for unit testing of services by mocking repositories. Sometimes, services provide convenient methods on top of the repository.

Hope it might be of some help to you.

Answer (score 1):

A1. When making changes to your code the more often you run the unit tests the faster you will get feedback on whether the behavior they were written to assert has been affected, so the more often the better! Unit tests should be very fast and running several hundred should only take a couple of minutes at most, but it might be worth looking into [infinitest](http://infinitest.github.io/) (if working with java, i expect an alternative will exist for .net etc) it is a plugin to eclipse and automatically runs your unit tests when eclipse builds your project. It is clever enough to run only the tests that have been affected since the last time it ran, e.g. if you update a test, or if you update some "application" code that is covered by some unit tests the specific tests will be executed.

A2. Unit tests will cover many different scenarios that will call your services + daos many times, using "real" services will make it difficult to guarantee the results of each call (and setting up the data for each test can be painful), but also the results can be slow. It's usually better when unit testing to mock these services and testing them independently with integration tests.